# Disable Gmail "muting" feature to prevent accidental muting

Tags: gmail, mute

I recently muted a conversation by accident and thus didn't see replies to it, so I went back and found others via https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#muted which I had unintentionally muted. Since I never deliberately mute conversations, it would be nice to turn this off.

I understand that disabling keyboard shortcuts may reduce the chance of this, but it'd be nice to keep those on.

Is there a way to disable muting in Gmail altogether?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to disable muting, but there is a workaround without having to disable keyboard shortcuts altogether.

Under Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts just change the shortcut key for muting to a combination of characters that you are unlikely to accidentally type.

I changed this shortcut as well, as I had the same problem with accidentally muting conversations!

Comment: You need to first go to Settings > Advanced and enable Custom Keyboard Shortcuts.